Power state changes when working on virtual machine
I'd like to add an automatic test to check if my product handles properly during power state changes (entering to sleep and waking from sleep). Unfortunately, using a VMWare based machine I try to add a relative wake of 10 seconds followed by instant start of sleep mode.
pmset relative wake 10;pmset sleepnow

However, it seems like the VM never wakes up as it should after 10 seconds.
Is it a known issue with virtual machines.
Any idea how to simulate this scenario differently ?

Using VMWare for testing power state changes, like entering sleep mode and waking up, can be problematic as VMs might not handle these transitions accurately. The pmset relative wake 10; pmset sleepnow command may not work as expected in a virtual environment because VMWare often doesn't fully emulate the hardware-level power state changes that a physical machine undergoes.
To simulate this scenario, consider running tests on actual hardware or use tools designed for power management testing that can better emulate these conditions. Alternatively, testing on different VM software that better supports power state transitions might help.
